# How can I implement a user interface that supports drag and drop?

Tags: java, user-interface, components

I'm currently developing a Java application that converts information from analogue sensors to MIDI messages (and hopefully OSC in the future), which can then be routed to a music production program (Ableton Live, Pro Tools etc.).

I'm a bit confused about how to implement the user interface though... An exact example of the kind of interface I would like to create is that of Reaktor (an application which allows you to build your own audio DSP units from small predefined modules). Here is a link to a screenshot of the application:

http://media.soundonsound.com/sos/jun02/images/reaktor06023.gif

Ideally, I would have onscreen components (shapes, rectangles, lines) representing software objects and how they are connected together. The idea is that the user can drag and drop "modules" (which actually represent software objects) and wire them together and build a custom system. So for example, to convert a stream of sensor information to MIDI, they would drop a "Sensor Module" on to the screen, and wire the output into a "MIDI Converter Module", then wire the output of that into an "Output Module" or something similar.

I probably haven't done a great job of explaining my problem, so please feel free to ask any questions for clarification.

Thanks very much in advance!

Chris

Answer (score 0):

It's not a hard thing. It's even documented in the official Java starter guides by Oracle.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/dnd/

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I should have said, I've had a look at that, but I'm not sure how I could implement the drawing of cables in between modules. In addition to that, I'm unclear on how you can drag JComponents around the screen? I thought they were held in position by the layout manager you set?